# How to read users outlook email using Oauth2?

Tags: email, oauth, outlook, imap, hotmail

I'm building a service which scans peoples email for specific `PDF` attachments and indexes them. I implemented this with `OAuth2` for `Gmail` using their extensive [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) which works perfectly fine.

I now want to implement the same for `outlook/live/hotmail`. So I searched around, and I mainly read that [you](http://www.geekwire.com/2013/outlookcom-supports-imap-oauth-login/) [can](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440163.aspx) "Connect to Outlook.com `IMAP` using `OAuth 2.0`" ([tutorial here](http://www.geekwire.com/2013/outlookcom-supports-imap-oauth-login/)). The thing is that this implements a full `IMAP` connection. As far as I know this is more meant for aftermarket applications with which the user can view and send his email, not for applications which need to download some email in the background (like mine).

I haven't worked with `IMAP` from within code, but the main problems I see with this now is that:

1. If I read emails they will be set to "read" in the inbox of the user, which I obviously don't want (I don't want to interfere with the normal email usage of the user).
2. I will need to either stay connected with all email inboxes, or constantly loop through all email inboxes to get new emails.

My questions are actually;

1. Is there no other way than `IMAP` to get users `outlook.com` email?
2. Or are my problems actually not problems and should I just create an `IMAP` "receiver" for all the `outlook` email accounts?

Comment: Point 1 is not a problem. You just need to use body.peek variants of fetch to avoid setting the read flag.

Comment: And as for item 2, you should probably have one connection per account, and use the IMAP `IDLE` extension, which is by and large ubiquitous.

Comment: Have you gone through this ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440163.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In answer to point #1, according to [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442918/max), you can use `body.peak` to avoid this.

In answer to point #2, according to [triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee), you can connect to all of the accounts and then use an IMAP extension called `IDLE`.

In answer to point #3, I found the [Outlook REST API](https://dev.outlook.com) which includes options to read the email and you can call `GET https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages` on a regular basis to get all messages in the user's account or you can call `GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/messages` on a regular basis to get all messages in the user's inbox. You can find a full list of the REST APIs operations [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations).

In answer to point #4, I believe that some of your problems are problems and others aren't. I believe that you don't have any technical problems. However, I believe that you are correct that IMAP is not designed for applications like yours as is shown in the [Wikipedia article on IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) which reads (bold is mine),

> In computing, the Internet Message Access Protocol (IMAP) is an Internet standard protocol used by **e-mail clients** to retrieve e-mail messages from a mail server over a TCP/IP connection. IMAP is defined by RFC 3501.

Also,  in [RFC 3501](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc3501) which defines the original IMAP protocol it refers to email clients which from the absract reads (bold is mine),

> The Internet Message Access Protocol, Version 4rev1 (IMAP4rev1) allows a **client** to access and manipulate electronic mail messages on a server.